# How to use Pandas to get the count of every combination inclusive

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out what combination of clothing customers are buying together. I can figure out the exact combination, but the problem I can't figure out is the count that includes the combination + others.

For example, I have:

```
Cust_num  Item    Rev
Cust1     Shirt1  $40
Cust1     Shirt2  $40
Cust1     Shorts1 $40
Cust2     Shirt1  $40
Cust2     Shorts1 $40
```

This should result in:

```
Combo                  Count
Shirt1,Shirt2,Shorts1    1
Shirt1,Shorts1           2
```

The best I can do is unique combinations:

```
Combo                 Count
Shirt1,Shirt2,Shorts1   1
Shirt1,Shorts1          1
```

I tried:

```
df = df.pivot(index='Cust_num',columns='Item').sum()
df[df.notnull()] = "x"
df = df.loc[:,"Shirt1":].replace("x", pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))
col = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(col)
df2.groupby([0]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

But that is just the unique counts.

Comment: I feel like this is one sort of problem pandas would not be suitable for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
grouped_item = df.groupby('Cust_num')['Item']
subsets = grouped_item.apply(lambda x: set(x)).tolist()
Count = [sum(s2.issubset(s1) for s1 in subsets) for s2 in subsets]
combo = grouped_item.apply(lambda x:','.join(x))
combo = combo.reset_index()
combo['Count']=Count
```

Output:

```
  Cust_num                   Item  Count
0    Cust1  Shirt1,Shirt2,Shorts1      1
1    Cust2         Shirt1,Shorts1      2
```

Comment: How is finding subsets finding inclusive combination of `df['Item']`? Subsets are not combinations. Below is output of what you doing: `{' Shirt2', ' Shorts1', ' Shirt1'}: True` followed by `{' Shorts1', ' Shirt1'}: True` and then `{' Shorts1', ' Shirt1'}: True`. Then you sum then to get `[1,2]`. I agree my approach i did is wrong so is yours. I would think `@ResidentSleeper` has correct answer.

Comment: `@Chris`,  I think you need to find combination of `Item` first which would give you your `subsets`. You would sum unique. FYI, I did not mock your comment. I was asking a question just like you asked me a question. I did not throw a hissy or downvote you. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @LeeMtoti Apologies for a strong language. I've deleted it. BTW, `grouped_item` contains a combination of each `CustN`'s choice of clothing. `lambda x: set(x)` was implemented for a `issubset` comparison. As you pointed out, `issubset` returns `True` if and only if a set is contained in other set, which I still believe is what OP wants.

Comment: I believe the term _combination_ is subtle misleading. My understanding is a set of each customer's choices of Item. Hope this makes my answer and intention clearer.

Comment: Apologies if the language wasn't correct. I wasn't sure how to describe it. I tried this with the first 1,000 customers, and it worked! I'm running it now with the full list.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a combination of items first.

[How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

I used the function from **Dan H**'s answer.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def all_subsets(ss):
    return chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(0, len(ss)+1)))

uq_items = df.Item.unique()

list(all_subsets(uq_items))

[(),
 ('Shirt1',),
 ('Shirt2',),
 ('Shorts1',),
 ('Shirt1', 'Shirt2'),
 ('Shirt1', 'Shorts1'),
 ('Shirt2', 'Shorts1'),
 ('Shirt1', 'Shirt2', 'Shorts1')]
```

And use `groupby` each customer to get their items combination.

```
ls = []

for _, d in df.groupby('Cust_num', group_keys=False):
    # Get all possible subset of items
    pi = np.array(list(all_subsets(d.Item)))

    # Fliter only > 1
    ls.append(pi[[len(l) > 1 for l in pi]])
```

Then convert to `Series` and use `value_counts()`.

```
pd.Series(np.concatenate(ls)).value_counts()

(Shirt1, Shorts1)            2
(Shirt2, Shorts1)            1
(Shirt1, Shirt2, Shorts1)    1
(Shirt1, Shirt2)             1
```

Comment: This probably works, but I keep getting a "Memory Error". I'll have to look for a solution for the memory issue as I can't use my desktop for this project (sensitive data).

Comment: I did the first 1000 customers and it worked! Any suggestion for low memory laptops?

Comment: @lys_dad The accepted answer has already solved your memory problem, right?

Comment: It does, yes. But thank you for your elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but you can use:

```
df = df.groupby(['Cust_num'], as_index=False).agg(','.join).drop(columns=['Rev']).set_index(['Item']).rename_axis("combo").rename(columns={"Cust_num": "Count"})
df['Count'] = df['Count'].str.replace(r'Cust','')
```

---

```
combo                   Count                 
Shirt1,Shirt2,Shorts1     1
Shirt1,Shorts1            2
```

Answer (score 0):

My version which I believe is easier to understand

```
new_df = df.groupby("Cust_num").agg({lambda x: ''.join(x.unique())})

new_df ['count'] = range(1, len(new_df ) + 1)
```

Output:

```
                            Item      Rev count
                        <lambda> <lambda>      
Cust_num                                       
Cust1      Shirt1 Shirt2 Shorts1      $40     1
Cust2             Shirt1 Shorts1      $40     2
```

Since you do not need the `Rev` column, you can drop it:

```
new_df = new_df = new_df.drop(columns=["Rev"]).reset_index()

new_df
```

Output:

```
  Cust_num                    Item count
                          <lambda>      
0    Cust1   Shirt1 Shirt2 Shorts1     1
1    Cust2          Shirt1 Shorts1     2
```

This edit is to respond to `@Chris` by looking at his approach written using list comprehension. He created an list of sets:

```
[{' Shirt1', ' Shirt2', ' Shorts1'}, {' Shirt1', ' Shorts1'}]
```

Then next step finds the subsets:

```
for s1 in subsets:
    for s2 in subsets:
        if s2.issubset(s1):
            print("{}: {}".format(s2,s2.issubset(s1)))
```

Output:

```
{' Shirt2', ' Shorts1', ' Shirt1'}: True
{' Shorts1', ' Shirt1'}: True
{' Shorts1', ' Shirt1'}: True
```

You asked me to explain myself and I did. However after thinking about it, I realized your approach was wrong too. As such I was not mocking you, but thanking you for making me think about my solution. Also thanks to @ResidentSleeper for his solution.

Comment: `@Chris` thank for mocking my comment and down voting my answer. I did not downvote your answer out of the spirit of learning from each other.

Comment: `@Chris` thanks for removing the downvote. Whole point is to learn from each other while helping each other.